# How to dispose local components within form class

Tags: c#, winforms, idisposable, fxcop

I am facing `FxCop` warning for local component variable even after proper handling of dispose on component. Code looks like:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colm = null;
        try
        {
            colm = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            colm.HeaderText = @"Header text";

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colm);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (colm != null)
                components.Add(colm);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am adding new component `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` inside code into `DataGridView`. Warning is something I need to dispose newly created `colm` inside code, but already added in container support of form which will dispose all components on form's dispose.

`FxCop` warning is:

**CA2000    Dispose objects before losing scope In method 'Form2.Form2_Load(object, EventArgs)', object 'colm' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'colm' before all references to it are out of scope.    WindowsFormsApplication1    Form2.cs    36**

Any fixes for such scenarios?

Comment: As an FYI: not all warnings apply 100% of the times.

Comment: CA2000 is notoriously unreliable.  There are lots and lots of existing questions about it, be sure to read them before starting yet another question about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Will this approach work even if I ignore the warning? I mean no other changes required to handle it.

Comment: By design, the `components` container calls `Dispose` on each of its children when it is disposed.

Comment: As a side note: You shouldn't attach event handlers to an event of a base class of your class. Override `protected void OnLoad(EventArgs)` instead. Try-Finally and If shouldn't be necessary when you add the `colm` to `components` right after it's creation. But that is just nitpicking. You solution looks solid to me.